# Angular/Firebase - Guard runs before Firebase initialization is done

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

See issue here (open console):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su5p89?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

I've imported and called `initalizeApp` in my `AppModule` like this:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),

    // Firebase
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,

    // App
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Then I created a guard that looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {

  /** @ignore */
  constructor() {}

  canLoad(): boolean {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  canActivateChild(): boolean {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  private performCheck() {
    return !!firebase.auth().currentUser;
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
export const Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'hello'
  },
  {
    path: 'hello',
    component: HelloComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

However, this yields the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase
>   App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()
>   (app/no-app). [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has
>   been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
>       at error (index.cjs.js:361)
>       at app (index.cjs.js:244)
>       at Object.serviceNamespace [as auth] (index.cjs.js:302)
>       at AuthGuard.performCheck (auth.guard.ts:35)
>       at AuthGuard.canActivate (auth.guard.ts:29)
>       at eval (check_guards.ts:121)
>       at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (defer.ts:59)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.ts:231)
>       at Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:212)
>       at TakeOperator.call (take.ts:72)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at eval (zone.js:892)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:262)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

Which when looking at other issues means the app haven't initialized Firebase yet, which is odd since I do that before anything else.. And in theory the guard should run **AFTER** all of this happens, right?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would configure the guard differently because for some reason this line:

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

is causing a second initialisation and there is no `initializeApp()` method called which causes the error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'; // instead of firebase
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {

  /** @ignore */
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  canActivateChild(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.performCheck();
  }

  private performCheck(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user.pipe(map((user) => {
      if (user) {
        // user is logged in
        return true;
      }
      // user is not logged in
      return false;
    }), 
    take(1));
  }
}
```

[updated stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-equydb)

Comment: Interesting workaround. Like you say it doesn't really make any sense. I even opened an issue on this, will be interesting to see what they say about it.